# Querying a column in Parse

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have an iOS app that allows users to save GeoPoints to a Parse.com database table. Its a Google Maps app that lets users submit Lat/Long coordinates that will be displayed on the map once the Points have been approved by an admin type person.

I created a table called Point on Parse.com to save this information and the table has the following fields in addition the default ones that are created for you:

- approved (String)
- point (GeoPoints)

When a new row in the table is created (new Point is submitted by a user), "approved" is always set to "0" and "point" will contain the Lat/Long of a point that has been uploaded.

Once the "point" has been approved by an admin, "approved" is set to "1".

I query the table to display all the GeoPoints that have been approved (set to "1").

I can get all the rows that has been set to "1" but I dont know how to access the "point" field. I need to get the "point" for each row to display it to a map.

Here is what I have to query the table for all Points where "approved" is set to "1"

```
// Query the Database to get Points
PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Point"];
[query whereKey:@"approved"  equalTo:@"0"];

[query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error)
 {
     if (!error)
     {
         // The find was successful
         NSLog(@"Successfully Retrieved %d Number of Points", objects.count);

         // Display the found Points as Markers

         for (PFObject *object in objects)
         {
             NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);

             // Tried to do this but does not work
             NSLog(@"%@", object.point);
         }
     }
     else
     {
         // Show errors
         NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
     }
 }];
```

I tried the following once I had an array of the objects but this does not work.

```
// Tried to do this but does not work
NSLog(@"%@", object.point);
```

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is:

```
PFGeoPoint *point = object[@"point"];
```

Refer to the [PFGeoPoint class reference](http://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFGeoPoint.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You can also go with subclassing for ease of use. Refer to [iOS Guide Subclassing](https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#subclasses/iOS). Don't forget to register the subclass in your AppDelegate.

```
//Point.h
#import "Parse/Parse.h"

@interface Point : PFObject  <PFSubclassing>

@property (nonatomic) BOOL approved;
@property (nonatomic, strong) PFGeoPoint *geoPoint;
+ (void)findApprovedPointsWithBlock:(PFArrayResultBlock)resultBlock;

@end

//Point.m
#import "Point.h"
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>

@implementation Point

@dynamic approved;
@dynamic geoPoint;

+ (NSString *)parseClassName {
    return @"Point";
}

+ (void)findApprovedPointsWithBlock:(PFArrayResultBlock)resultBlock {
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Point"];
    [query whereKey:@"approved"  equalTo:@YES];

    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *points, NSError *error) {
        resultBlock(points, error); 
    }];
}

@end

// Somewhere in your code
[Point findApprovedPointsWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        for (Point *object in objects) {
            NSLog(@"%@", object.objectId);
            NSLog(@"%@", object.geoPoint);
        }
    }
    else {
    }
}];
```